# Apache FOP and xsi:schemaLocation - how to ignore?

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have in my XSL-FO file a xsi:schemaLocation just to know, what attributes/tags are available.
Unfortunatelly I getting an exception from the transformet:

org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Invalid property encountered on "fo:root": xsi:schemaLocation

On the FopFactory I see, there is a method called ignoreNamespace, but it doesn't work or I don't know how to write it properly. I got:

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
fopFactory.ignoreNamespace("xsi:schemaLocation");
```

How to do it right?

My root of the XSL-FO looks that:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            font-family="Arial" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format http://www.xmlblueprint.com/documents/fop.xsd">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ignoreNamespace function takes the namespace identifier, which in this case is the URL: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance. The following should fix the issue for you:

```
fopFactory.ignoreNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Comment: Thx it works. I tried xsi:schemaLocation, http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format and http://www.xmlblueprint.com/documents/fop.xsd but not this one you mentioned ;)